# get first row fo each group SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, sqldf

I have data like below.
I would like to get the top choice for each gender from the following data

```
subjectID <- c("1", "2", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "2", 
       "0", "0", "2", "2","2","1","2","1","0","2")
gender <- c("M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
    "M", "F", "M", "M", "F","M", "F", "M", "F",  "F")

 selection <- data.frame(subjectID, gender)
       subjectID <- c("1", "2", "0")
       subject <- c("Maths", "Music",  "English")

    subjects <- data.frame(subjectID, subject)
```

I have tried mapping the choices by descending order as below :

```
 favourite <- sqldf("SELECT  a.gender, b.subject, COUNT(a.subjectID) as `no of selections`
              FROM selection a
              JOIN subjects b
              ON (a.subjectID  = b.subjectID )
              GROUP BY a.subjectID, a.gender
              ORDER BY a.gender, `no of selections` DESC
              ")
```

BUT, I would like to get the following table where i get the top choice for eachgender :

```
gender <- c("F", "M")
subjects <- c("Music", "Maths")
mostfav <- data.frame(gender, subjects)
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are runing MySQL 8.0, you can use `RANK()` in a subquery to rank the records by subject count for each gender, and filter on the top record per group in the outer query (if there are top ties, `RANK()` preserves them):

```
SELECT gender, subject, no_of_selections
FROM (
    SELECT  
        se.gender, 
        su.subject, 
        COUNT(*) as no_of_selections,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY se.gender ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM selection se
    JOIN subjects su ON se.subjectID  = su.subjectID
    GROUP BY se.subjectID, se.gender, su.subject
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY gender DESC
```

In earlier versions, where window functions are not availabe, one option is to filter with a `having` clause that returns to top count per gender:

```
SELECT  
    se.gender, 
    su.subject, 
    COUNT(*) as no_of_selections
FROM selection se
JOIN subjects su ON se.subjectID  = su.subjectID
GROUP BY se.subjectID, se.gender, su.subject
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM selection se1
    WHERE se1.gender = se.gender
    GROUP BY se1.subjectID, se1.gender
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Notes:

- I changed the table aliases to make them more meaningful
- You should the `subject` column to the `GROUP BY` clause to make your query runnable under sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_MODE`, which is by default enabled starting MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions in the SQL:

```
SELECT gs.*
FROM (SELECT s.gender, su.subject, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.gender ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM selection s JOIN
           subjects su
           ON su.subjectID  = s.subjectID
      GROUP BY s.gender, su.subject
     ) gs
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```